# sorting through integers in multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wanting to have the user input a name and highscore, I then want to check if this highscore is greater than any of the high scores in the array. I think the .isdigit() has something to do with it but need further assistance.

```
HighScores = (("FredROX",43651),("ACE51",41032),("RangiBoi",40080),
              ("Prince",38987),("DaiZ",35346),("ACE51",35344),("WASSABI",34513),
              ("MasterG",31095),("RSGuru",30521),("SnipeU",25948))


name = input("Please input a name")
score = int(input("Enter a highscore"))


def Print_Scores():
   #Function to print the high score table
   #allow function to access HighScores from outside the function
    global HighScores
    for x in HighScores.isdigit():
        if score > HighScores:
            HighScores.append(name, score)
    print(HighScores)        








#call the printing function
Print_Scores()
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate over the result of a call to `HighScores.isdigit`, but `HighScores`, presumably, is a `list`. You are probably getting an `AttributeError`. In the future, you should post the *full error including the stack trace*. It is unclear what you expect to accomplish with your `for` statement, I think you need to clarify. Also, your `global` statement is unnecessary. And your function is suppose to `print` the high scores, but it `appends` to a list of high scores? Finally, that isn't a multidimensional array, that is a tuple of tuples.

Comment: So, if you are getting that `NameError`, it's likely that you are using Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than this:

```
for x in HighScores.isdigit():
    if score > HighScores:
        HighScores.append(name, score)
print(HighScores)
```

Do this:

```
for x in HighScores:
    if score > x[1]:
        HighScores.append((name, score))
print(HighScores)
```

Remember to make score an int if you are getting input.

`isDigit()` checks whether a character is a digit.
Make `HighScores` a list, not a tuple by using square brackets around it rather than parentheses.

Comment: I am getting this when after I entered the name jo. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\highscore comparing.py", line 6, in <module>
    name = input("Please input a name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jo' is not defined

Comment: I figured out why I was using 2.7 idle instead of 3.

Comment: Did you change `HighScores` to a list, using square brackets, instead of a tuple? Are you using python 3?

Comment: HighScores is python 2, because thats what the teacher gave us as a list. But the rest is python 3, how can I convert it to python 3?

Comment: I've now used the square brackets but am getting. TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()

Comment: This code does not work as written. It produces an error because you are passing append two parameters rather than passing a 2-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should probably look something like this. The score is always the second item in each tuple, so you can select that value immediately instead of checking isDigit. You then want to append the name and score in a tuple to that list.

```
for tup in HighScores:
    if score > tup[1]:
        HighScores.append((name, score))
```

Comment: Why should a "print_scores" function `.append` to a list of high scores?

Comment: Sorry, it shouldn't be called print_scores that was from a previous task. I should probably rename it to something like append_scores

Comment: Im getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mr\Downloads\highscore comparing.py", line 6, in <module>
    name = input("Please input a name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'brendan' is not defined

Comment: @Droid2 that is likely entirely unrelated to the source of your current error (which you never actually provided). You should start a different question for that. Actually, though, I suspect you are being taught Python 3 but have a Python 2 interpreter installed, and you should be using `raw_input`. If `raw_input` works, that means you are using Python 2, because Python 3 removed that function.

Comment: Thanks for that I was indeed using 2.7 idle.

Comment: Now I'm getting error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mr/Desktop/append_highscores.py", line 27, in <module>
    Print_Scores()
  File "C:/Users/Mr/Desktop/append_highscores.py", line 16, in Print_Scores
    HighScores.append((name, score))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: In the code you have pasted here, HighScores is a list (square brackets). Your error suggests you have normal parentheses around HighScores.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# import itemgetter
from operator import itemgetter

# HighScores should be a list, not a tuple. That way you can modify it
HighScores = [("FredROX",43651),("ACE51",41032),("RangiBoi",40080),
              ("Prince",38987),("DaiZ",35346),("ACE51",35344),("WASSABI",34513),
              ("MasterG",31095),("RSGuru",30521),("SnipeU",25948)]

# cleaned up the input
name = input("Please input a name: ")
score = int(input("Enter a highscore: "))


def Print_Scores():
   #Function to print the high score table
   #allow function to access HighScores from outside the function
    global HighScores
    # explained below
    if score > max(HighScores, key=itemgetter(1))[1]:
        HighScores.append((name, score))
    print(HighScores)        

#call the printing function
Print_Scores()
```

The line

```
if score > max(HighScores, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
```

deserves explanation.

The `itemgetter(1)` part is a function that is equivalent to this:

```
def itemgetter(i):
    def f(x):
        return x[i]
    return f
```

So `itemgetter(1)` returns the second item of a sequence.

Now we use that function as the key to max, so that it finds the element that has the greatest score.

```
max(HighScores, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Then we take that and get its second item (its score)

```
max(HighScores, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
```

And if it's less than the score they entered, we add their score to `HighScores`.

For future reference, it's probably better if you don't append to the list inside of a function called `PrintScores` as people will not expect that. I would do it directly after you get the user input, like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

HighScores = [("FredROX",43651),("ACE51",41032),("RangiBoi",40080),
              ("Prince",38987),("DaiZ",35346),("ACE51",35344),("WASSABI",34513),
              ("MasterG",31095),("RSGuru",30521),("SnipeU",25948)]


name = input("Please input a name: ")
score = int(input("Enter a highscore: "))

if score > max(HighScores, key=itemgetter(1))[1]:
    HighScores.append((name, score))

def Print_Scores():
   #Function to print the high score table
   #allow function to access HighScores from outside the function
    global HighScores
    print(HighScores)        

#call the printing function
Print_Scores()
```

Of course at that point you don't really need the `PrintScores` function and you can just `print(HighScores)`

Comment: Why should a "print_scores" function `.append` to a list of high scores?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm only doing it because that's what his code did. He had the right idea, just didn't know the syntax

Comment: No need for a library.

Comment: @パスカル it's built into python, so you don't need to download anything external. It just makes things easier. You could also just say `lambda t: t[1]`

Comment: Or you could just directly index the list.